Building Scipy from source for windows Arm64 ends in lld link errors
im using scipy build from source
While executing
python -m pip install -r requirements/build.txt -r requirements/dev.txt
matplotlib is in error.
llvm 18.1.0rc
I built Openblas from source for arm64, gave the path to the PKG-CONFIG-PATH environment variable, and pasted it inside the build folder created after the first failure of the below command.
python dev.py build
    lld-link: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use /errorlimit:0 to see all errors)
    flang-new: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    [60/1300] Compiling C object scipy/special/cython_special.cp312-win_arm64.pyd.p/meson-generated_cython_special.c.obj
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    Build failed!

i also see
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/flang-new.EXE
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/flang-new.EXE - broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!



ERR:
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
  The Fortran compiler

    "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/flang-new.EXE"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: 'C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/johndoe/scipy/build/meson-private/cmake_xsimd/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-0hh5mx'
    
    Run Build Command(s): C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/johndoe/scipy/venv/Scripts/ninja.exe -v cmTC_b1f75
    [1/4] C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\FLANG-~1.EXE -cpp   -fms-runtime-lib=dll_dbg -E C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\johndoe\scipy\build\meson-private\cmake_xsimd\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-0hh5mx\testFortranCompiler.f > CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f-pp.f && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_ninja_depends --tdi=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\FortranDependInfo.json --lang=Fortran --src=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f-pp.f --out=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f-pp.f --dep=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f-pp.f.d --obj=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f.obj --ddi=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f.obj.ddi --src-orig=C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\johndoe\scipy\build\meson-private\cmake_xsimd\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-0hh5mx\testFortranCompiler.f"
    [2/4] "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_ninja_dyndep --tdi=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\FortranDependInfo.json --lang=Fortran --dd=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\Fortran.dd @CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\Fortran.dd.rsp
    [3/4] C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\FLANG-~1.EXE -IC:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\johndoe\scipy\build\meson-private\cmake_xsimd\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-0hh5mx -fms-runtime-lib=dll_dbg -ffixed-line-length-72 -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f.obj -c CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f-pp.f
    [4/4] C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --msvc-ver=1941 --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir --rc=rc --mt="" --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f.obj  /out:cmTC_b1f75.exe /implib:cmTC_b1f75.lib /pdb:cmTC_b1f75.exe.dbg /version:0.0 /machine:ARM64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console   -libpath:"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/lib/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/atlmfc/lib/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/ucrt/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files/LLVM/lib" -libpath:"C:/Program Files/LLVM/lib/clang/18/lib/windows"  && cd ."
    FAILED: cmTC_b1f75.exe 
    C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --msvc-ver=1941 --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir --rc=rc --mt="" --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir\testFortranCompiler.f.obj  /out:cmTC_b1f75.exe /implib:cmTC_b1f75.lib /pdb:cmTC_b1f75.exe.dbg /version:0.0 /machine:ARM64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console   -libpath:"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/lib/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/atlmfc/lib/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/ucrt/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/arm64" -libpath:"C:/Program Files/LLVM/lib" -libpath:"C:/Program Files/LLVM/lib/clang/18/lib/windows"  && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1f75.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    no such file or directory
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



WOA wheels are still in their infancy, due to lack of CI and devices within the developer community. This will change over the next year. In the meantime there are unofficial wheels available from https://github.com/cgohlke/win_arm64-wheels
